# Converting docx table into html (keeping all formatting) or an image to use in html

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-docx

I've used python-docx to create some tables using a specified style format in my docx file. I now need to use these tables with this same formatting. Is there a way I can either convert the table including all of the formatting and styles, colours etc.  to html? Or failing that a simple (automated) way of making the table into a figure which could be used?

Comment: Save the docx file as a .html form using python code. I tried manually it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Suraj M, that sounds very useful. Do you have an example or a link which shows how to do this? Does it preserve all of the formatting, for exanple cell colouring , font size etc.?

Comment: I added sample code below to convert docx to html

Comment: Below I posted two codes use `win32` module to keep formatting and images.

Comment: If below code sample is usefull can you vote me.

Answer (score 4):

To covert Docx to HTML use below code:

Below code do not identify the tables and images from docx.It convert docx to html but not preserve tables and images.

```
import mammoth

Docx = open("docx_file.docx", 'rb')
html = open('html_filename.html', 'wb')
document = mammoth.convert_to_html(Docx )
html.write(document.value.encode('utf8'))
Docx.close()
html.close()
```

To keep formatting and images use win32 package for converting docx to html.

```
import win32com.client

doc = win32com.client.GetObject ("docx_InputFile.docx")
doc.SaveAs (FileName="Html_FileName.html", FileFormat=8)
doc.Close ()
```

Comment: Thanks Suraj M. This will be very useful. I am however getting a few errors and am stuck with:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221020,'Invalid syntax', None,None)
in Moniker of win32. Do you happen to know how to fix it? My searches haven't proved very useful and any advice found so far hasn't worked

Comment: @oben which version of python you are using?

Comment: the version I've got is 2.7

Comment: @oben I tested my code on python 3.6 It works fine for me. Are you passing docx path as a absolute path.Don't pass relative path.

Comment: Yep using absolute paths

Comment: hey guys can we append different word document in html file ...i don't want to create new html file i just wanted to append the data using win32 is it possible?

Comment: @oben  - did you solve the com_error error? I have the same

Answer (score 0):

I can't find suitable solution, that supports conversion with formatting and styles. But you may try to convert docx to jpg by using this: [DOCX to JPG API](https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-jpg). Python library and snippets for this service are here: [ConvertAPI/convertapi-python](https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-python)

Comment: Thanks SmartWaddles, do you know if it is possible to automate that it only converts the table and not the whole document? I can't view the first link unfortunately

Comment: @oben, it looks like it converts the whole document into jpg-file. You may use something like [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) or some Python modules to extract tables from your initial docx file into docx only with tables, that you need to convert.

Comment: Thanks @SmartWaddles I'm not sure I can do that for this work as the formatting is tied to the particular style template of the document if copied to another I think the formatting will change.